# Is this a factory method?

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern

Factory pattern consist of classes that implement particular interface. Does it always have to be an interface? Would it still be a factory method when I have subclasses that inherit from other class not an interface?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what you're asking - can you provide an example?

Comment: OK, concrete product in Factory method implement an interface. My question is if I "substitute" the interface with a parent class would it still be a factory method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) does not *necessarily* have anything to do with interfaces (in terms of a language's `interface` keyword or construct).  You can have factory methods that create class instances, and may construct a subclass instead of the base class just as easily as if you're using interfaces.

For example, see [this Wikipedia example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#Java_2).  Here, a `Room` is created, with subclasses of the main type creating different concrete types of `Room` instances.  This is still using the Factory method pattern, even though there is no "interface" involved.

> My question is if I "substitute" the interface with a parent class would it still be a factory method?

Yes - it would still be a factory method.

Comment: GoF use in their description <<interface>> so that bit confused me. Thank you.

Comment: @lunar You're always creating some instance of an object that fulfills a "contract" of some form - depending on the language, this may be an interface, or a base class, or some other mechanism.

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I ask a maybe bit offtopic question - refers to factory abstract patter this time. Is there a point to create abstract factory class that creates just one type of objects?

Comment: @lunar It depends on the language and design you choose.  Typically, you may want a factory method, but in most languages, there's a way to make that part of the class itself (ie: a static method in the class).  For example, if you're making a class to represent an angle, using `Angle CreateFromDegrees(double)` or `Angle CreateFromRadians(double)` can make the API far more clear than using a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean that. 
Interface in the context of interaction, control (creation) and not the Java's `interface`